# Marking a old question answered when the OP told it's?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask if for question that the OP told it work, but didnt marked it answered, if moderator's should mark it. As I seen the "Community" user keep them pooping in the active's question feed.

Latest example that was active today (because of Community's user)

[Windows Server DHCP import/export scopes using netsh.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/634333/windows-server-dhcp-import-export-scopes-using-netsh-exe) (I didnt leave a note, but yes you need to erase before the import, like the OP's wrote)

What is the stance SF usually take on that ? as it's not the first time I seen such question ( unanswered, but answered :) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moderators can't mark an answer as accepted and I wouldn't want to do it on behalf of a another user.

See [Allow moderators to mark flagged question as answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169017/allow-moderators-to-mark-flagged-question-as-answered) and the various duplicates. In short: It's not going to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the link ! I thougth it was available to do, but it answer me, as it's just not an option

Comment: @yagmoth555 remember that stackexchange exists as a set of community driven sites.  Moderators are a necessary evil (although if I recall correctly from the early days moderators as being necessary was an interesting debate)

Comment: @JimB the moderator hat is not easy, but it's necessary. by moderating you cant make everyone happy. Community driven is a large term btw. As on technet forum mod can mark the answer, but it's wrote that they did it. As a community site, they wanted to attract more contributor as a lot of users does not actually come back to mark (and if they come back, they can unmark, they see it that way). On SE they prioritized the up'ing system, as upped answer are displayed first (and upping give more point), kinda why I like womble answer, I now see it the good way.

Comment: @yagmoth555 TechNet is different because it's presumed that the TechNet moderators know what the answer is.  In the case of SF the community knows what the answer is rather than the mods.

Comment: @JimB I agree, but my question was specific at first, when the OP itselft tell the answer, but didnt mark it.

Answer (score 5):

Upvote the good answer, to make it obvious that the community believes it is the correct answer.  The green tick means, specifically and solely, "the question asker believes this is the correct answer".

Comment: I like how you tell it, it change my perception for upvote

Answer (score -6):

The main problem with this that so the questions are left open indefinitely, only because of the untrustworthy behavior of the OP. On my opinion, questions should be allowed to left opened only if there is *known* that an answer exists, or it will maybe exist in the future, but nobody found it until now. But it is only my opinion, it seems the SE has other ideas and the always growing list of the undoned work somehow doesn't annoy them.

What can be done: doublecheck, if there is any of the possible close reasons. Destroying something can be done very efficiently here, in most cases it is enough if you flag it for close with any reason. It is especially okay, for example, if an essentially similar question, *but* with an accepted answer, appeared since the original opening - closing questions as duplicates is the most simple.

Comment: Hi Peter, my point was more to give mod a right, as when a question is wrote and the OP itself answer it, or tell "thanks, it answer me", but does not mark the answer. (like the example I gave).

Comment: @yagmoth555 I think their problem with it that the mod would "say" something in the name of the OP. Nobody likes to communicate in others' name. But, I think, in such cases it would be highly useful if a highly upvoted answer could get an automatic green pipe.

Comment: @yagmoth555 But I don't think it would be a tipical case. What is much more common, is that the OP is long forgotten, but new and new answers are only coming and coming to the question, because the question comes always for in the "unanswered" list.

Comment: I don't like the idea of auto mark, but just a mod mark, and only when the OP told it worked with solution gave in an answer, as for up vote it only show what the community think is the answer, but for the same reason you give, as the unanswered allow re-come in the list

Comment: @yagmoth555 Mods are exception handlers, they should be needed only in exceptional cases. I wouldn't say a disappeared OP exceptional.